# How to change ActionBar Tab styles in API 14 and above

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to fit 5 tabs at the top using the ViewPager view. I need those 5 tabs to fit on the screen width. It does not, so I was able to decrease the text size to make it fit, but then the text is too small. So now I am trying to take away some of the padding for each tab like so:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTextTheme</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item> -->
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTextTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

Except nothing happens. In fact the tabs completely disappear. Is there something more specific I should be doing? Thanks.